# Renderizado del mayor elemento con contenido Error

Tags: untagged

Me aparece un mensaje de Error en el renderizado del mayor elemento con contenido. La puntuación de la página: https://neurinomavestibular.es/
es de 100 pero con ese mensaje de error

Comment: Esto es una pregunta o un clickbait para aumentar tráfico? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]

Comment: Ustedes perdonen. Parece que en mi ignorancia me he equivocado de sitio al preguntar sobre el informe de Pagespeed insights.